# How to fill detail of Foreign key used in other models of Python class

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I have the following user and order class:

```
class User(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)
     username = models.CharField(max_length=240)
     password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
     last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
     is_superuser = models.IntegerField()
```

Order table

```
class Order(models.Model):
    orderid = models.AutoField(db_column='orderId', primary_key=True)
    orderuserid = models.ForeignKey('User', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='users', db_column='orderUserId')
    orderamount = models.IntegerField(db_column='orderAmount', blank=True, null=True)
```

Now my question is that I want to create a new order from existing user , so how can I auto fill the orderuserid field in the Order table when create a order by the user. I am confused how the serializer will work now.

My serializer class is

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orderid = serializers.IntegerField
    orderuserid = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    orderamount = serializers.CharField

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ('orderid','orderuserid','orderamount')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Orders.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

and View

```
class OrdersView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

and the error is KeyError at /api/orders
'request'

Comment: you mean when the user for example visit `/new/order` he don't want to type his username?

Answer (score 0):

In the new DRF, you can do this:

```
orderuserid  = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
```

It will fill the `orderuserid` if the user is authenticated.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know a lot about DRF but isn't this unsafe because the user can change the input value and pretend to be someone else?

Comment: @mohammedqudah this will input only the id of the authenticated user. So, the only way to pretend to be someone else is to log in with their account.

Comment: i know, but if he inspected the code he will see `<input type="hidden" value="some id, and simply he change it">`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply send current login user in context and use it in create method of serializer just like this.

**View**

```
class OrdersView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = OrderSerializer(data=request.data, context={'user': request.user})
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**Serializer**

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orderid = serializers.IntegerField()
    orderuserid = serializers.ReadOnlyField(required=False)
    orderamount = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Orders
        fields = ('orderid','orderuserid','orderamount')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        validated_data.update({'orderuserid': self.context.get('user')})
        return Orders.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: thanks, as I am trying backend for first time as a iOS developer I found one more idea that I am saving user id in my app keychain and then will pass that id directly in the form.